# Bootstrap and fixed iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my current project I want to add an iframe. To be more specific, I want to show an iframe whenever a user clicks on a certain region (on an anchor tag) of the page he or she would be viewing and it should be shown in a way it contains the CSS property `position: fixed;`. After taking a look on the Bootstrap website and after some searching, I could not find much concerning this.

Could anyone explain me how to make a responsive fixed `<iframe>`?

I used the [following](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lh1fym0/) code:

```css
.other-content {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 1000px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1080px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-content">
    Some other content goes in here
  </div>

  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 fixed">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

(It might not exactly similar here on Stackoverflow to the result I got on Jsfiddle)

**Edit**:

After some more fiddling, my question comes down to the following:
I want a child element's width with `position: fixed` CSS property to always have the exact same width as the Bootstrap container element, so that it will always stay within the container. This is what my code looks like right now (try resizing the result fiddle window):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8trba0b5/2/)

I do not wish to change any of the Bootstrap CSS (such as removing padding) and as for height, this does not matter, it can be put on `height: auto;`. How would I make this possible?

Comment: what do you expect when you say `responsive fixed <iframe>?` should the iframe be responsive and fixed??

Comment: Basically it should be fixed and still fit within the screen, e.g. I open a mobile phone and make the iframe fit within its screen size.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have adjusted your styles:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
}

iframe {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

I have also added class `container` to `embed-responsive` so the two can have the same width.

Comment: I don't necessarily want a video to fit in. I want an iframe width to be equals to the container.

Comment: Consider removing left and right padding from .container

Comment: The problem I am experiencing is the that the `<iframe>` element width doesn't change and therefor moving out of the container, making the right side of the iframe impossible to see on a smaller sized screen. Removing padding here won't help. Height would increase as the width of the `<iframe>` decreases on smaller sized screens.

Comment: Oh you meant removing the padding so I could use `width: inherit`? Not sure if Bootstrap uses the padding for something specific...

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully this solves the issue.

Comment: Adding the padding to the `<iframe>` does not solve the issue. The `<iframe>` element is not always present in the DOM and that is why I put all of the content in a container, such as the`<iframe>` element aswell. Also I do not really wish to use embed-responsive class if it has nothing of importance to my goal. I think it is only used for a video element.

Comment: I also added class container, and have amended the .fixed styles

Comment: Your answer comes really close to what I want, but I guess I shouldn't have used a youtube video as example (because the Bootstrap documentation website also used it in an example). I want to load a page by using an iframe, thus the iframe should just fit within the container. When I look at the fiddle, I see it will get outside the container where there is padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can not take the width of the container of if the inner `div` is fixed. You can achieve it using JavaScript.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-content">
    Some other content goes in here
  </div>

  <div class="fixed">
  <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0">
    </iframe>
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
  /*padding: 0;*/
}

.other-content
{
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 1000px;
  width: auto;
}

.fixed
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  /* How do I fix the padding issue? */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
  .fixed
  {
    /*since width of parent turns to width: auto; so will the following rule be
    and the width turns not to be right. How should I make this equals to the parent element
    aswell when the parent's width is set to auto? */
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var widthOfContainer = $(.container ).width();
$(function() {
  $(".fixed").width(widthOfContainer);
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8trba0b5/3/).

Comment: That's not what I meant to happen. I just want the iframe to fit inside the container element. That's all there is to it. When the screen size gets smaller, so does the container element, thus the fixed element should also become smaller. But using a width of inherit adds the padding and once the screen is smaller than 767 px or something, the width of the container is not set, making the use of `width: inherit` (nearly?) impossible. https://jsfiddle.net/oafdaLzv/ The blue (with the class `.fixed`) looks perfectly inside the container element, but it needs to be fixed and containing the iframe

Comment: I did not understood what happens when the width is less than 767px. Could you please explain it again?

Comment: It seems like Bootstrap uses a mediaquery: `@media (min-width: 768px).container {width: 750px};`. So if a screen smaller, there is no value set for the width property. The result I would like to see: https://i.gyazo.com/da2130b9b7088cdf2212aaf61d1d0495.png

Answer (score 0):

Just add this CSS rule

```
iframe.embed-responsive-item{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Also Changes to your existing CSS

```
 .fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  /* width:100%; */ /* remove the width*/
  left:8px;
  right:8px;
}
```

---

```css
.other-content {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 1000px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  left:8px;
  right:8px;
}

iframe.embed-responsive-item{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-content">
    Some other content goes in here
  </div>

  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 fixed">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the right side of the iframe is not visible on smaller sized screens. I want the iframe to always stick inside the container. Height might be changed because of that, so a `height: auto;` would be just fine. It's just about the width.